# Why does sumoselect.css work on localhost but not on live server?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I am using the sumoselect.css to have multiselect listboxes.  Everything works fine on my test machine but when I upload everything to the live server the css does not work.  From what I have gathered I have a reference problem but I can't seem to figure it out.  I am using masterpages and so I will show the header section of the masterpage for your review. I am not sure if the js files need to be listed in a particular order.  Thank you for your guidance. I have read other articles here that talked about referencing but I am not having any luck.

```html
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://www.acmenotary.com/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.acmenotary.com/jquery.sumoselect.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="https://www.thenotaryfamily.com/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" />
</head>
```

I have changed the reference lines to all types of variations without any luck.

Comment: what does it show in the network tab?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Tell me where to look for the network tab,

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It appears that I did not have a secure request on another js file which blocked the others from loading.  I corrected everything and it works now as expected.